# React-Bootsrap Col extra spacing right

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

[image: Picture]

I want all the corder components pulled into a corner of the screen using react and react-bootstrap. Whatever I try, the Col wrapping the SVG component adds extra space on the right. For the left side corner this does not matter but on the right, this does not allow the components to be placed in the corner. I have tried right : 0, changing the col size, overwrite the container css, and use box-sizing with no success. Her is my code for the parent component and the corner component.

```
return (
    <div>
      {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
      {searchParams.get("user") != null &&
        <svg onClick={redirectAccount} width="60px" height="60px" style={{ position: "fixed", right : "48%", padding : "10px"}} viewBox="0 0 24.00 24.00" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.00024000000000000003">
          <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"/>
          <g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"> <g id="style=doutone"> <g id="add-box"> <path id="vector (Stroke)" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M1.25 8C1.25 4.27208 4.27208 1.25 8 1.25H16C19.7279 1.25 22.75 4.27208 22.75 8V16C22.75 19.7279 19.7279 22.75 16 22.75H8C4.27208 22.75 1.25 19.7279 1.25 16V8ZM8 2.75C5.10051 2.75 2.75 5.10051 2.75 8V16C2.75 18.8995 5.10051 21.25 8 21.25H16C18.8995 21.25 21.25 18.8995 21.25 16V8C21.25 5.10051 18.8995 2.75 16 2.75H8Z" fill="#000000"/> <path id="vector (Stroke)_2" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M12 7.00744C12.4142 7.00744 12.75 7.34323 12.75 7.75744L12.75 16.2427C12.75 16.6569 12.4142 16.9927 12 16.9927C11.5857 16.9927 11.25 16.6569 11.25 16.2427L11.25 7.75743C11.25 7.34322 11.5858 7.00744 12 7.00744Z" fill="#BFBFBF"/> <path id="vector (Stroke)_3" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M17 12C17 12.4142 16.6642 12.75 16.25 12.75L7.76476 12.75C7.35055 12.75 7.01476 12.4142 7.01476 12C7.01477 11.5857 7.35055 11.25 7.76477 11.25L16.25 11.25C16.6642 11.25 17 11.5858 17 12Z" fill="#BFBFBF"/> </g> </g> </g>
        </svg>
      }
      <div id='wrapper'>
        <EditQuotes showEdit={ showEdit } database={barz} handleShowEdit={handleShowEdit} showAdd={handleShowAdd}/>
      </div>
      <div id='wrapper'>
        <NewQuote shown={showAdd} handleShowEdit={handleShowEdit} handleShown={handleShowAdd}/>
      </div>
      <Container fluid style={container}>
        <UseScreenOrientation/>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={2} lg={"auto"} style={{padding : 0}}>
            <Corner rotation="0" />
          </Col>
          <Col>
            {searchParams.get("user") === null &&
              <Topnav setDataBase={handleDataBase} showEdit={handleShowEdit}/>
            }
          </Col>
          <Col xs={2} lg={"auto"} style={{padding : 0}}>
            <Corner rotation="90"/>
          </Col>
        </Row>

        <Row >
          <QuoteContainer dataBase={dataBase} quote={barz[ranInt].data} />
        </Row>

        <Row>
          <Col xs={2} lg={3} style={{padding : 0}} className="fixed-bottom">
            <Corner rotation="270"/>
          </Col>
          <Col className='text-center'>
            <Button onClick={genRanInt}>Refresh</Button>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={2} lg={3} style={{padding : 0, right: 0, position: "fixed", bottom : 0, blockSize: "fit-content"}}>
            <Corner rotation="180" />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
```

And the corner component:

```
import { ReactComponent as CornerImg } from '../img/corner.svg';


export default function Corner(props) {

  const style = {
    transform: "rotate(" + props.rotation + "deg)",
    width: "70%",
    height: "auto",
  };

  return (
    <CornerImg style={style} />
  );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: absolute;`.

Change this...

```
<Col xs={2} lg={3} style={{padding : 0, right: 0, position: "fixed", bottom: 0, blockSize: "fit-content"}}>
  <Corner rotation="180" />
</Col>
```

...to this.

```
<Col xs={2} lg={3} style={{padding : 0, right: 0, position: "absolute", bottom: 0, blockSize: "fit-content"}}>
  <Corner rotation="180" />
</Col>
```